# How to use MySQL trigger to reject duplicate entries?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to learn how to use mySQL triggers. This is an example.

my example table : exam_results

```
STUDENT_ID (primary)
EXAM_NAME
RESULT_1
RESULT_2
OPTION_1
```

I used the following example in ASP.net code to insert student exam results.

```
INSERT INTO exam_results (EXAM_NAME,RESULT_1,RESULT_2,OPTION_1) 
VALUES (@exam_name,@result_1,@result_2,@option_1);
```

Now what I need to know is how to prevent duplicate EXAM_NAME for user without using UNIQUE key in mysql but with a following condition.

I want my INSERT to go through if there the trigger is not true. 
Trigger to be activated before INSERT.

The trigger condition EXAM_NAME and OPTION_1 = 2 (need to fail INSERT)

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER `exam_results`.`exam_results_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `exam_results` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 
           FROM exam_results 
           WHERE EXAM_NAME= NEW.EXAM_NAME 
             AND OPTION_1 = (2)
          )
    ) THEN
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' 
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'INSERT failed due to duplicate exam name';
END IF;
END
```

Whats the best way I could do this ? (I know how I to do with UNIQUE_KEY but trying to learn how to do it with triggers.)

Comment: What should happen if `OPTION_1 <> 2` or it is NULL?

Comment: I only want to check OPTION_1. Its not a problem if anything else.

Comment: *prevent duplicate EXAM_NAME for user* You must add a condition by user into checking SELECT in a trigger. Now you check duplicate over whole data regardless of user. *I used the following example in ASP.net code to insert student exam results.* Where is the info about what user's result is inserted? *without using UNIQUE key* Why ??? *I know how I to do with UNIQUE_KEY* Show to prove, please... be aware, it is not trivial because of additional condition by OPTION_1.